# Bootstrap button group collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I have a group of buttons group:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-justified" role="group" id="nav_bar">
            <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="row">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#Setup1" data-parent="#accordion">Setup1</a>
                    <div id="Setup1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-justified" role="group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">MAIN</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">EXEC</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">ROUTER</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#Setup2" data-parent="#accordion">Setup2</a>
                    <div id="Setup2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-justified" role="group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">MAIN</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">EXEC</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">ROUTER</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in output this is: 
[image]

but I cant figure out, how to make collapse one group, when you expand other. Could someone help with that? 
I was trying to play with panels, but it's unsuitable, because i need a style, which showed on attached image. And in panels only text is clickable.
Thanks

Comment: Try this http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse, You have given accordian as a Id attribute but it should be class

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by setting up your elements with bootstrap properly.

But you can also extend the collapse by:

```
 $('.btn').on('click',function(){
    $('.panel-collapse').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('in');
    }):
 });
```